# AngularAMD fails to load controller after r.js

Tags: requirejs, r.js, angular-amd

It seems like I miss running r.js over code with AngularAMD.

```
.when('/', angularAMD.route({
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    controllerUrl: 'controllers/home',
    data: {
          name: 'home'
    }
}))
```

I have the following route defined which works fine as long as I don't run r.js, but after I do I'm getting the following error,

```
Uncaught Error: undefined missing controllers/home
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the name of your js file for the home controller named `home.js`?

If not - then you will want the `controllerUrl` to equal the exact name without the `.js` at the end. - `controllers/homeCtrl` or `controllers/homeController` - mattering if that is how you've named your controller's js file.